# Restrain scattered jitter points within a violin plot by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

A following is used to generate the violin plot in ggplot2 :

```
ggplot(violin,aes(x=variable,y=log(value+0.5),color=Group)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width") + 
  geom_jitter(aes(group=Group), position=position_jitterdodge()) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="crossbar", mapping=aes(ymin=..y.., ymax=..y..), 
     width=1, position=position_dodge(),show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, margin=margin(0.5, unit="cm")))
```

A resulting plot looks like following;

[image]

As you can see,  some points are jittered outside the boundary of violin shape and I need to those points to be inside of the violin.  I've played different levels of jittering but have had any success. I'd appreciate any pointers to achieve this.

Comment: where does the data `violin` come from?

Comment: maybe try `ggforce::geom_sina`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a little bit old question but I think there is a better solution.

As @Richard Telford pointed out in a comment, `geom_sina` is the best solution IMO.

simulate data

```
df <- data.frame(data=rnorm(1200), 
                 group=rep(c("A","A","A", "B","B","C"),
                           200)
                 )
```

make plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=data,x=group,color=group)) +
  geom_violin()+
  geom_sina()
```

result

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi @akh22, I am glad it works for you. If you like the answer you may want to upvote and/or mark as the answer to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The package `ggbeeswarm` has the geoms quasirandom and beeswarm, which do exactly what you are searching for: https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**

Using the function geom_quasirandom from package geom_beeswarm:


> The quasirandom geom is a convenient means to offset points within categories to reduce overplotting. Uses the vipor package.

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_violin(width = 1.3) + geom_quasirandom(alpha = 0.2, width = 0.2)
```

[image]

**Option 2**

Not a satisfactory answer, because by restricting the horizontal jitter we defeat the purpose of handling overplotting. But you can enlarge the width of the violin plots (`width = 1.3`), and play with `alpha` for transparency and limit the horizontal jitter (`width = .02`).

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_violin(width = 1.3) + geom_jitter(alpha = 0.2, width = .02)
```

[image]